# 'How many people came to your party?' or 'How many people did come to your party?' is correct

Tags: grammar, questions, past-simple

I don't understand why question 'How many people came to your party?' is correct instead of 'How many people did come to your party?'. Is it any grammar rule?

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: Because I did some excercise in workbook and key answer suggested that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either may be correct. *How many people *did* come?* is contrastive: it would be appropriate if your hearer had been talking about the people who didn't come. But without some such context, *do* support is unnecessary because the interrogative phrase, *how many people*, acts as the **subject** of the question: when that is the case, there is no inversion or *do* support.

> *Who came?*, not *Who did come?*, except in contrastive contexts, but
>   *Who(m) did you invite?*, not *Who(m) you invited?*, because here *who* is the **object** of *invite*.

Answer (score 2):

Either sentence would be grammatically correct, but it is more common to hear "How many people came to your party?"